# CachedRowSet update a record in H2

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update, h2, cachedrowset

I have a H2 DB with a table

```
CREATE TABLE income_expense
(
  amount VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ondate VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

and some random data like `INSERT INTO income_expense VALUES ('10','Something','2015-04-15');`

then I connect to this DB with *JDBC* and try to do an *UPDATE* through *CachedRowSet*:

```
public void doUpdate()
{
    try
    { 
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        setConnection(
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/thisdb", "sa", ""));

        CachedRowSet crs2 = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs2.setType(CachedRowSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
        crs2.setConcurrency(CachedRowSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        crs2.setCommand(
                "SELECT amount, name, ondate FROM income_expense");
        crs2.execute(getConnection());
        crs2.absolute(1);
        crs2.updateString("amount", "22");
        crs2.updateString("name"  , "33");
        crs2.updateString("ondate", "44");
        crs2.updateRow();
        crs2.acceptChanges();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error occured." + e);
    }
}
```

this update fails with a message *javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncProviderException: 1 conflicts while synchronizing*.

What am I doing wrong to update a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... `CachedRowSet` *UPDATE* worked only after I added a *PRIMARY KEY* to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE income_expenses ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE income_expenses ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

and specified numbers of columns which form a key for uniquely identifying a row and included that column in a `SELECT`:

```
//First column from a command will be the key
crs2.setKeyColumns(new int[]{1});
crs2.setCommand("SELECT id, amount, name, ondate FROM income_expense");
```